# How to reconnect to mysql after receiving mqtt message in python?

Tags: python, mysql, mqtt

I am using python to subscribe to one topic, parse JSON and store them in the database. I have problems with loosing connection with MySQL because it can't be opened too long. Message that I receive is below

```
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (2006, 'MySQL server has gone away')
```

I managed to remove it by increasing timeout, but that is not good solution, because I can't know how long will the system need to wait for the message.
Is there a possibility I could create connection only when message is received?

i tried to add the connection details into on message, and then closing it but I still have the same problem

```
def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
```

sql="""INSERT INTO data(something) VALUES (%s)"""
    data = ("some value")
    with db:
        try:
            cursor.execute(sql,data)
        except MySQLdb.Error:
            db.ping(True)
            cursor.execute(sql,data)
        except:
            print("error")
            print(cursor._last_executed)

but then that variable is not visible outside this function. What is the best practise for this.

The part of code for making connection is bellow

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import MySQLdb
import json
import time
#mysql config
try:
    db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost",  # your host 
                     user="admin",       # username
                     passwd="somepass",     # password
                     db="mydb")   # name of the database
except:
    print("error")
```

So as you see, I have created one connection to mysql at the begging, and if there is no message for time longer then defined timeout my script stops working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
cur = db.cursor()
try:
    cur.execute(query, params)
except MySQLdb.Error:
    db.ping(True)
    cur.execute(query, params)
```

`db.ping(True)` says to reconnect to DB is the connection was lost. You can also call `db.ping(True)` right after `MySQLdb.connect`. But to be on the safe side I'd better wrap `execute()` into `try` and call `db.ping(True)` in `except` block.